# VS 2008, is there a way to search properties like the old vb6/EVB? CTRL+SHIFT?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, search, filter, properties

I really miss the CTRL+SHIFT+CHAR searching of a property in VS 2008 that older IDE's had... typing CTRL+SHIFT+T got you to "tabindex" then Tag when pressed again.  They dropped it in VS 2002 I believe, and the closest I could find to restoring any functionality like it was acorn's property window filter, which isn't exactly functional.  Does anyone know of a way to get this functionality back?  I hate having to browse through 30-40 properties in design mode, when a CTRL+SHIFT+T would get me right to text.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use intellisense? Type variable., the moment you type the . you get a list of all possible members, the further you type the more it gets narrowed down. Also, the last member you used will be favoured.

Comment: Intellisense is for text editing I believe. What the author is talking about is the ability to search the property grid for a specified property. In Delphi you simply click on the left-hand side of the property grid and start typing, and control moves to the property you type. That doesn't work in any version of VS. It would be nice if there was a shortcut, dialog or some other way to search for a specified property. It's very tedious to have to do an eyeball search every time I want to set a control's size, color, font or other property. Anyone have any ideas? Tips?